# Permission denied with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want users of my app to have access to see profile of other users that is accessed via real-time database. I'm referencing to db via

`ref.once('users/'+uid, snapshot => snapshot.child('users/'+uid).val())`

Rules i have:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
   },
}
```

I don't get why i can't access `users/:uid` even though simulator gives `success` message by ticking `read` and running simulation on `<firebaseURL>/users`.

If i set `".read": true"` under `rules` it does allow me to read the data, but that may bait me later on if i would want to implement stuff that i don't want to be available to unauthorized users.

**Edit (solution):**

The problem was with referencing to firebase. Instead of `firebase.database.ref('users')` I was referencing too root itself by `firebase.database.ref()`.

That reference caused to apply default `read/write` rules.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect the code to do. But `snapshot.child('users/'+uid).val()` => `snapshot.val()` seems like a first problem.

Comment: I'm trying to read single user details so thats why i'm using `snapshot.child('users/'+uid).val()` and it does work, however the `rules` i've set doesn't allow me to read this data via that function.

Comment: You're missing a quote " right after the ".read: it should be *".read": true,*

Comment: @Jay indeed, was writing the code from memory and missed one quote, good catch, though that doesn't fix the problem why i can't read the data even though simulation is successfull :\

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is expected from this code *ref.once('users/'+uid, snapshot => snapshot.child('users/'+uid).val())*

Comment: @Jay Sure. It should return user object that looks like `{ username: 'joe', role: 'user', updatedProfile: false }`. And i do receive this object when `".read"` is set for `"rules"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give `".read": "auth != null"` to allow all authorised users to read data under `users` object and prevent unauthorised users from reading it.

Comment: The thing is, i would like to allow unauthorised users to read that data aswell.

Comment: It should, but it doesn't. Thats what is odd for me.

Comment: "If i set ".read": true" under rules it does allow me to read the data, but that may bait me later on if i would want to implement stuff that i don't want to be available to unauthorized users." <- In your question you says it allows

Comment: I think may be your db query is wrong. You want to access individual user profile or all user profiles at same time?

Comment: By that statement you mentioned i meant this: https://jsfiddle.net/tfLswm5t/ About query, it works fine for getting single user. I assume i would go with `snapshot.child(`users`).val()` if i would like to get all users.

Comment: Your query structure is wrong, try this:
 
 firebase.database().ref('users').once('value', data=> {
  data.val(); <= this should give all your users.   
 })

Comment: Your query is trying to read root snapshots and then get user object from it and it should fail since you haven't given read permission to root.

Comment: Oh, finally found that. Indeed, what I was doing is I was exporting `const ref = firebase.database.ref()` and then importing as `ref.once....`. Gonna edit my post with that solution. Appreciate for taking time to troubleshoot that one!

Comment: Happy to help :)